# Compile fable generated code with webpack

Tags: webpack, fable-f#

My test.fsx looks like:

```
module Test
#r "./node_modules/fable-core/Fable.Core.dll"
open Fable.Core
open Fable.Import.Browser
type ItemCompletedData    = {itemsCompleted:int}
type AddData              = {text:string}
[<Pojo>]
type ActionData =
  | ItemCompleted of ItemCompletedData
  | Add of AddData
let test = (Add {text="hello world"})
console.log(test)
```

Compile it with:

```
node node_modules/fable-compiler/index.js --projFile test.fsx -o ./js/
```

webpack.config.js looks like:

```
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: ["./js/test.js"]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    publicPath: ".",
    filename: "[name].js"
  }
  ,devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "./"),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000
  }
};
```

Running webpack with the following command:

```
node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --devtool source-map
```

That will give warnigns:

> WARNING in ./~/.0.7.26@fable-core/umd/Symbol.js 3:24-31 Critical
>   dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies
>   cannot be statically extracted
>
> WARNING in ./~/.0.7.26@fable-core/umd/Util.js 3:24-31 Critical
>   dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies
>   cannot be statically extracted

When opening an html file that uses main.js I get an error in the console:

```
Symbol.js:3 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
```

The symbol.js comes from `fable-core/umd/Symbol` (in the fable generated script). When I change it manually to: `fable-core/Symbol` (for all fable-core dependencies) then I can webpack compile without warnings and do not get errors in the page.

How can I prevent this error without having to manually change the fable output?

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question I was going through the steps and tried adding `-m es2015` to the fable compiler command.

That was the solution.

Now that fable code can load I only need to solve the problem that riot generated js code creates. I need to load the tags after setting riot.mixin so I load them in nested requiejs umd statements (maybe that causes an error).

```
require riot
  ... require tag1 tag2 ...
```